# How to make a Lyx shortcut for a math expression

Tags: lyx

In typing up my work I frequently use the same mathematical expressions, for example \leq \epsilon. In Lyx I must type it this way and then invoke the math function; or else select the symbols from the math toolbar.  It would save me a lot of time to have a keyboard shortcut for this combination and several others.

I looked at tools-preferences-edit-shortcuts hoping I could create my own shortcuts. I find I have the cua bind file.  That seems to offer shortcuts for the Greek letters, but I can't get them to work.  For example it lists  math-insert \alpha as Alt+M G A but no matter how I try it,  that doesn't insert anything into my document.

Can anyone tell me how to create shortcuts for some of my common multi-symbol uses?

Comment: Does `math-insert \leq \epsilon` do what you want?

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't call it short.

Comment: Ah so the problem is that you cannot add that as a shortcut? Can you please give the exact steps you took (e.g. I clicked here, entered this, etc.) and what happened?

Comment: ALT+M G A should work, this is not a custom shortcut, you're supposed to press M while holding the alt, release both the alt and the m, then press G then A.  If this does not work something might be wrong with your shortcuts

Comment: Following your directions Elad, I did get Alt M G A to work.  I will try scottkiosy's suggestion later today.

Comment: Okay, got it working.  Shft-E it is.  Thanks, guys.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the already known keyboard shortcut was entered the wrong way.